# What are the answers to Yerhva's trivia questions?

Tags: deathloop

In Karl's Bay, there's a machine that asks a series of trivia questions. What are the answers to these questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: The questions can appear in any order, but the answers are always shown in the same order, so I've included the number associated with each answer.

- **Q:** AEON graces this island as kaleidescopic jewels upon the neck of the world's greatest beauty. What seeks the Program?

  **A:** 3: The advancement of human potentiality and enlightenment.
- **Q:** Decades ago, warmongers toyed with the temporal tides eddying about Blackreef. Their sigil-marked temples stand still. What named their doomed enterprise?

  **A:** 3: Operation Horizon
- **Q:** Blackreef boasts a bountiful feast for the senses. Which transcendent work towers above the island's myriad other artistic pursuits?

  **A:** 7: The nose, chin, and eyes of Charlie Montague
- **Q:** The Bay, the Rock, and labyrinthine Updaam wear AEON colors proudly, but that decor belies their history. From whence came the peculiar names that grace them?

  **A:** 5: They date back to a lost fishing colony
- **Q:** From what seed did AEON spring?

  **A:** 6: The shared ambitions of Harriet Morse, Egor Serling, and Dr. Wenjie Evans
- **Q:** Before AEON's arrival, Blackreef slept in frozen utero, awaiting new purpose. Who then made landfall, reawakening her from slumber?

  **A:** 2: Colt Vahn and Egor Serling, on a voyage of discovery
- **Q:** Sink your toes into the dark earth and let the vibrations of her voice course through your bones. From whence did this island derive her name?

  **A:** 8: Coastal coral formations
- **Q:** The wriggling, writhing energies of the Loop have been harnessed to gift us with abilities beyond our biological potential. What birthed our trinkets and slabs?

  **A:** 7: Dr. Wenjie Evans personally engineered each one.
- **Q:** Karl's Bay has worn many faces, most as lost to time as the mysterious Karl himself. What was its most recent incarnation prior to AEON's arrival?

  **A:** 3: A military air base
- **Q:** Harriet Morse is the gatekeeper, Blackreef the gate. A veil hangs across the threshold. What do we discover when it parts?

  **A:** 4: The Great Beyond